# How can I create a custom 'Week of Year' using a CASE Statement BETWEEN two dates over multiple weeks?

Tags: case, looker-studio

I'm currently trying to create a custom 'Week of Year' in Data Studio, starting on Saturday and ending on Friday. After many other attempts, I'm now trying to use a CASE statement.

The CASE statement is:

```
CASE
  WHEN
    date BETWEEN DATE(2022,07,30) AND DATE(2022,08,05)
    THEN "WEEK 29"
    DATE BETWEEN DATE(2022,08,06) AND DATE(2022,08,12)
    THEN "WEEK 30"
    DATE BETWEEN DATE(2022,08,13) AND DATE(2022,08,19)
    THEN "WEEK 31"
  ELSE NULL 
END
```

This however, results in 'Syntax error: Expected "ELSE" or "END" but got "Date"'.

I guess this is a double question but does the above mean that I am unable to use the CASE statement more than once, e.g. can only apply it to Week 29 and not future weeks?

The second is, am I making this harder than it needs to be and there is an easier way to create a custom 'Week of Year' starting on Saturday and ending on Friday?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every branch of a `CASE` expression in SQL needs to begin with either the `WHEN` or `ELSE` keywords (the latter can only occur at most once, at the end of the `CASE` expression).  Try using this version:

```sql
CASE WHEN date BETWEEN DATE(2022,07,30) AND DATE(2022,08,05)
     THEN 'WEEK 29'
     WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATE(2022,08,06) AND DATE(2022,08,12)
     THEN 'WEEK 30'
     WHEN DATE BETWEEN DATE(2022,08,13) AND DATE(2022,08,19)
     THEN 'WEEK 31'
     ELSE NULL  -- optional
END
```

Note that the `ELSE` branch in your `CASE` expression is optional here, since the default else value is `NULL`.